# javascript multiple calculation with percentage multiple, divide

Tags: javascript, calculator

*below HTML, i put it up to upload this question. you should ignore it.

I would like to execute multiple calculating. I've been searched and adopted my things in those but kept failing. so i think i need to renew every codes and need help.

there are 2 values, A and B. and calculating button.

when i press button, i want it to be calculated A x 5% x 100 / B.

i appreciate your help. thanks.

ignore this HTML

```
<form>
<div>
<h4>value 1:</h4>
<input type="text" id="value1">
<h4>value 2:</h4>
<input type="text" id="value2">
</div>
<div>
<h4>Operator:</h4>
<select id="operator" value="add">
<option value="add"> Add </option>
</select>
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="cal()"> Calculate </button>
<h2 id="result"></h2>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the below snippet.

Note that I've used your html to get the corresponding values by user input.

---

```js
const cal = () => {
  const A = value1.value,
        B = value2.value;
  const res = A * (5/100) * (100 / B);
  result.innerText = `My result is ${res.toString().replace(".", ",")}`;
  //console.log(res);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <h4>value 1:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="value1" value=10>
    <h4>value 2:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="value2" value=20>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Operator:</h4>
    <select id="operator" value="add">
    <option value="add"> Add </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="cal()"> Calculate </button>
  <h2 id="result"></h2>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks. it worked. but can i know how i can add some word around result? when result is 5, i want it to shown as a sentence like 'you have "5" things to do.' i would be really appreciate it!

Comment: Take a look at the edit. Don't forget to accept the correct solution :D

Comment: thanks! umm would you teach me how i put comma to result number? sorry to keep bothering you. thank you!

Comment: Check the latest edit. Do you mean to replace the dot with a comma?

Comment: i mean when number is too big like 10000000, i want it to be appeared as 10,000,000. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From `A X 5% X 100 / B`, I am understanding that you want to perform `((A X 5%) X 100)/B`.
Now ((A X 5%) X 100) can be simplified  to (A X 5). Even with any other interpretation, it will result in the same.

```js
function cal() {
  var input1 = document.querySelector("#value1").value;
  var input2 = document.querySelector("#value2").value;
  
  document.querySelector("#result").innerText = (input1 * 5)/input2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <h4>value 1:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="value1">
    <h4>value 2:</h4>
    <input type="text" id="value2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Operator:</h4>
    <select id="operator" value="add">
      <option value="add"> Add </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="cal()"> Calculate </button>
  <h2 id="result"></h2>
</form>
```